# Pulling data from mainframe to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mainframe

What are the possible ways to pull data from mainframe to hadoop?
Is there any ETL tool providing inbuilt feature for the same?
I wish to pull data from files and database

Comment: Can you be more specific than "mainframe files and databases" (IMS, DB2, CICS, VSAM, etc)?

Comment: all possible sources of data from mainframe

Comment: Looks like similar to this one **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132071/how-to-pull-data-from-mainframe-to-hadoop**

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it

1. You can use Synsort to pull the data. Synsort is the fastes way to pull data through ETL.
2. you can use ftp over hdfs to download the files from mainframe server

Comment: i can pull data from DB2 using sqoop also right?

Comment: yes if the data is in db2 datatbase.The above two ways are for file based data.

Comment: Can any etl tool connect to mainframe and hadoop like Talend , informatica etc