# How to replicate VSAM files (Mainframe) to Database?

Tags: db2, database-replication, mainframe, vsam

What is an efficient solution/technology (other than ETL) to do a near real-time replication of data from a VSAM file (Mainframe) to an RDBMS (outside Mainframe) ?

**Note**: This VSAM file has COM3 data, so the replication technology should be able to understand and transform this during the replication.

Comment: Not a good fit for StackOverflow, in multiple ways. On top of that, only your site knows what software and policies they have, and whether they'd like to spend something on something new (if they don't already have something), even if such a something exists. Talk to the technical staff at your site. No other choice.

Answer (score 1):

there is a product at IBM - VSAM transparancy that routes vsam calls to DB2; this can help in a migration process..  there is also federation server of IBM that gives transparancy to different sources

Comment: There may be any number of products, but it does not help the OP at all if their site doesn't have them.

Comment: This is a new use case to our environment, so we are open to hear options and analyze them further. does this IBM product support realtime replication ?